# Multiply 2 columns in sql and to sum all the results using SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I write a query to multiply to colums now i would like to sum up the result that i am getting can any one give me an idea

this is what i wrote

`select Rate,Qty,(Rate*Qty) as result 
 from tblName`

I will get result say for example `40 90` now i would like to sum these results

Comment: Sum over several rows? All columns? Any grouping in that?

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to achieve. If you were to explain what you are trying to calculate, it may be easier to help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Original Answer

```
select Sum(Rate) as Rate, Sum(Qty) as Qty, Sum(Rate*Qty) as Result from tblName
```

**EDIT** - Try this..

```
select 
     0 as TotalRow, 
     Rate,
     Qty,
    (Rate*Qty) as Result 
from tblName

UNION ALL

select 
     1 as TotalRow,
     Sum(Rate) as Rate, 
     Sum(Qty) as Qty, 
     Sum(Rate*Qty) as Result 
 from tblName

Order By TotalRow
```

Comment: Not individual sum i would like to get the sum of result values that i had after executing my query

Comment: Hi one more question i don't want to dsiplay `sum(rate)` and all as per in `Select 1` i just want to display `Sum(Rate*Qty)` is it possble

Comment: You could replace `Sum(Rate) as Rate,` with `NULL as Rate,` and `Sum(Qty) as Qty,` with `NULL as Qty,`

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT SUM(Rate*Qty) as Result
FROM tblName
```

Comment: Can i display the result individually like multiplying in one result and addition as other

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve